# What is the Definition of an Analytic Function?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

I read two definitions of Analytic functions

- A function is analytic at a point $x$ if there exist $r$ for which $B(x,r)$ has all points differentiable.
- The function should be infinitely differentiable so that it can be written as convergent power series.

How are these two definitions identical?

Comment: Where is the definition assuming infinite differentiability?

Comment: First, regarding "infinitely differentiable so that It can be written as convergent power series": That sounds like we think that infinitely differentiable functions must be given by power series. Not true (in real analysis). A better version of (2) would be just "the function is given by a convergent power series in a neighborhood of every point". Anyway, the two are equivalent, but this is not entirely trivial; you can find a proof in more or less any complex book.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich  Maybe less than more: a lot of the more application-oriented "complex variables" texts will just assume $f$ is continuously differentiable, rather than prove the Goursat theorem.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Gawd, I'd forgotten about those books. Gonna have nightmares tonight, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that an analytic function (as defined using definition (1), **not** assuming even that the derivative is continuous) is locally given by the sum of a Taylor series (and therefore is infinitely differentiable) is 
proven using the Cauchy-Goursat theorem (i.e. Goursat's version of the Cauchy integral theorem).  Once you have that, you can get the Cauchy estimates and prove local convergence of the Taylor series to the function.

Comment: I read your answer 5 times and I am not sure that I got it truly. So a function is said to be analytic at a point if it is infinitely differentiable at that point? Then by this definition and using Cauchy-Goursat theorem it can be shown that the corresponding Taylor series converges to the function? Did I get it right? :)

Comment: No.  A function $f$ is said to be analytic at $p$ if there is some open disk $B$ centred at $p$ such that $f$ is differentiable at all points of $B$.  Using the Cauchy-Goursat theorem, you can show that the Taylor series of $f$ around $p$ converges in $B$ to $f$.

Comment: Sorry for the silly question, I am just trying to learn. :)  But talking in real domain, if the function is just differentiable at a point then how it can be proved that it is infinitely differentiable at that point!? I think the weakest assumption to form a Taylor series is being infinitely differentiable? After that we could make the sum then we can discuss the convergency issues. Am I wrong?

Comment: I also took a look at [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function#Definitions).

Comment: This is for functions of a complex variable.  The result is not true in the real domain.

Comment: Yes, that was the point I was missing! :)